# Laravel Trying to access array null error

Tags: php, laravel

I have a simple php whois lookup script for my project. When i use this code in vanilla php it is working. But when i use this code in my Laravel project i got error. It is because i use different version of php or something. I have tried some of the answers from stackoverflow but it didnt help very much.

This is the code

```
<?php
/*************************************************************************
php easy :: whois lookup script
==========================================================================
Author:      php easy code, www.phpeasycode.com
Web Site:    http://www.phpeasycode.com
Contact:     webmaster@phpeasycode.com
*************************************************************************/

$domain = "example.com";

// For the full list of TLDs/Whois servers see http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/ and http://www.whois365.com/en/listtld/
$whoisservers = array(
    "ac" => "whois.nic.ac", // Ascension Island
    // ad - Andorra - no whois server assigned
    "ae" => "whois.nic.ae", // United Arab Emirates
    "aero"=>"whois.aero",
    "af" => "whois.nic.af", // Afghanistan
    "ag" => "whois.nic.ag", // Antigua And Barbuda
    "ai" => "whois.ai", // Anguilla
    "al" => "whois.ripe.net", // Albania
    "am" => "whois.amnic.net",  // Armenia
    // an - Netherlands Antilles - no whois server assigned
    // ao - Angola - no whois server assigned
    // aq - Antarctica (New Zealand) - no whois server assigned
    // ar - Argentina - no whois server assigned
    "arpa" => "whois.iana.org",
    "as" => "whois.nic.as", // American Samoa
    "asia" => "whois.nic.asia",
    "at" => "whois.nic.at", // Austria
    "au" => "whois.aunic.net", // Australia
    // aw - Aruba - no whois server assigned
    "ax" => "whois.ax", // Aland Islands
    "az" => "whois.ripe.net", // Azerbaijan
    // ba - Bosnia And Herzegovina - no whois server assigned
    // bb - Barbados - no whois server assigned
    // bd - Bangladesh - no whois server assigned
    "be" => "whois.dns.be", // Belgium
    "bg" => "whois.register.bg", // Bulgaria
    "bi" => "whois.nic.bi", // Burundi
    "biz" => "whois.biz",
    "bj" => "whois.nic.bj", // Benin
    // bm - Bermuda - no whois server assigned
    "bn" => "whois.bn", // Brunei Darussalam
    "bo" => "whois.nic.bo", // Bolivia
    "br" => "whois.registro.br", // Brazil
    "bt" => "whois.netnames.net", // Bhutan
    // bv - Bouvet Island (Norway) - no whois server assigned
    // bw - Botswana - no whois server assigned
    "by" => "whois.cctld.by", // Belarus
    "bz" => "whois.belizenic.bz", // Belize
    "ca" => "whois.cira.ca", // Canada
    "cat" => "whois.cat", // Spain
    "cc" => "whois.nic.cc", // Cocos (Keeling) Islands
    "cd" => "whois.nic.cd", // Congo, The Democratic Republic Of The
    // cf - Central African Republic - no whois server assigned
    "ch" => "whois.nic.ch", // Switzerland
    "ci" => "whois.nic.ci", // Cote d'Ivoire
    "ck" => "whois.nic.ck", // Cook Islands
    "cl" => "whois.nic.cl", // Chile
    // cm - Cameroon - no whois server assigned
    "cn" => "whois.cnnic.net.cn", // China
    "co" => "whois.nic.co", // Colombia
    "com" => "whois.verisign-grs.com",
    "coop" => "whois.nic.coop",
    // cr - Costa Rica - no whois server assigned
    // cu - Cuba - no whois server assigned
    // cv - Cape Verde - no whois server assigned
    // cw - Curacao - no whois server assigned
    "cx" => "whois.nic.cx", // Christmas Island
    // cy - Cyprus - no whois server assigned
    "cz" => "whois.nic.cz", // Czech Republic
    "de" => "whois.denic.de", // Germany
    // dj - Djibouti - no whois server assigned
    "dk" => "whois.dk-hostmaster.dk", // Denmark
    "dm" => "whois.nic.dm", // Dominica
    // do - Dominican Republic - no whois server assigned
    "dz" => "whois.nic.dz", // Algeria
    "ec" => "whois.nic.ec", // Ecuador
    "edu" => "whois.educause.edu",
    "ee" => "whois.eenet.ee", // Estonia
    "eg" => "whois.ripe.net", // Egypt
    // er - Eritrea - no whois server assigned
    "es" => "whois.nic.es", // Spain
    // et - Ethiopia - no whois server assigned
    "eu" => "whois.eu",
    "fi" => "whois.ficora.fi", // Finland
    // fj - Fiji - no whois server assigned
    // fk - Falkland Islands - no whois server assigned
    // fm - Micronesia, Federated States Of - no whois server assigned
    "fo" => "whois.nic.fo", // Faroe Islands
    "fr" => "whois.nic.fr", // France
    // ga - Gabon - no whois server assigned
    "gd" => "whois.nic.gd", // Grenada
    // ge - Georgia - no whois server assigned
    // gf - French Guiana - no whois server assigned
    "gg" => "whois.gg", // Guernsey
    // gh - Ghana - no whois server assigned
    "gi" => "whois2.afilias-grs.net", // Gibraltar
    "gl" => "whois.nic.gl", // Greenland (Denmark)
    // gm - Gambia - no whois server assigned
    // gn - Guinea - no whois server assigned
    "gov" => "whois.nic.gov",
    // gr - Greece - no whois server assigned
    // gt - Guatemala - no whois server assigned
    "gs" => "whois.nic.gs", // South Georgia And The South Sandwich Islands
    // gu - Guam - no whois server assigned
    // gw - Guinea-bissau - no whois server assigned
    "gy" => "whois.registry.gy", // Guyana
    "hk" => "whois.hkirc.hk", // Hong Kong
    // hm - Heard and McDonald Islands (Australia) - no whois server assigned
    "hn" => "whois.nic.hn", // Honduras
    "hr" => "whois.dns.hr", // Croatia
    "ht" => "whois.nic.ht", // Haiti
    "hu" => "whois.nic.hu", // Hungary
    // id - Indonesia - no whois server assigned
    "ie" => "whois.domainregistry.ie", // Ireland
    "il" => "whois.isoc.org.il", // Israel
    "im" => "whois.nic.im", // Isle of Man
    "in" => "whois.inregistry.net", // India
    "info" => "whois.afilias.net",
    "int" => "whois.iana.org",
    "io" => "whois.nic.io", // British Indian Ocean Territory
    "iq" => "whois.cmc.iq", // Iraq
    "ir" => "whois.nic.ir", // Iran, Islamic Republic Of
    "is" => "whois.isnic.is", // Iceland
    "it" => "whois.nic.it", // Italy
    "je" => "whois.je", // Jersey
    // jm - Jamaica - no whois server assigned
    // jo - Jordan - no whois server assigned
    "jobs" => "jobswhois.verisign-grs.com",
    "jp" => "whois.jprs.jp", // Japan
    "ke" => "whois.kenic.or.ke", // Kenya
    "kg" => "www.domain.kg", // Kyrgyzstan
    // kh - Cambodia - no whois server assigned
    "ki" => "whois.nic.ki", // Kiribati
    // km - Comoros - no whois server assigned
    // kn - Saint Kitts And Nevis - no whois server assigned
    // kp - Korea, Democratic People's Republic Of - no whois server assigned
    "kr" => "whois.kr", // Korea, Republic Of
    // kw - Kuwait - no whois server assigned
    // ky - Cayman Islands - no whois server assigned
    "kz" => "whois.nic.kz", // Kazakhstan
    "la" => "whois.nic.la", // Lao People's Democratic Republic
    // lb - Lebanon - no whois server assigned
    // lc - Saint Lucia - no whois server assigned
    "li" => "whois.nic.li", // Liechtenstein
    // lk - Sri Lanka - no whois server assigned
    "lt" => "whois.domreg.lt", // Lithuania
    "lu" => "whois.dns.lu", // Luxembourg
    "lv" => "whois.nic.lv", // Latvia
    "ly" => "whois.nic.ly", // Libya
    "ma" => "whois.iam.net.ma", // Morocco
    // mc - Monaco - no whois server assigned
    "md" => "whois.nic.md", // Moldova
    "me" => "whois.nic.me", // Montenegro
    "mg" => "whois.nic.mg", // Madagascar
    // mh - Marshall Islands - no whois server assigned
    "mil" => "whois.nic.mil",
    // mk - Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic Of - no whois server assigned
    "ml" => "whois.dot.ml", // Mali
    // mm - Myanmar - no whois server assigned
    "mn" => "whois.nic.mn", // Mongolia
    "mo" => "whois.monic.mo", // Macao
    "mobi" => "whois.dotmobiregistry.net",
    "mp" => "whois.nic.mp", // Northern Mariana Islands
    // mq - Martinique (France) - no whois server assigned
    // mr - Mauritania - no whois server assigned
    "ms" => "whois.nic.ms", // Montserrat
    // mt - Malta - no whois server assigned
    "mu" => "whois.nic.mu", // Mauritius
    "museum" => "whois.museum",
    // mv - Maldives - no whois server assigned
    // mw - Malawi - no whois server assigned
    "mx" => "whois.mx", // Mexico
    "my" => "whois.domainregistry.my", // Malaysia
    // mz - Mozambique - no whois server assigned
    "na" => "whois.na-nic.com.na", // Namibia
    "name" => "whois.nic.name",
    "nc" => "whois.nc", // New Caledonia
    // ne - Niger - no whois server assigned
    "net" => "whois.verisign-grs.net",
    "nf" => "whois.nic.nf", // Norfolk Island
    "ng" => "whois.nic.net.ng", // Nigeria
    // ni - Nicaragua - no whois server assigned
    "nl" => "whois.domain-registry.nl", // Netherlands
    "no" => "whois.norid.no", // Norway
    // np - Nepal - no whois server assigned
    // nr - Nauru - no whois server assigned
    "nu" => "whois.nic.nu", // Niue
    "nz" => "whois.srs.net.nz", // New Zealand
    "om" => "whois.registry.om", // Oman
    "org" => "whois.pir.org",
    // pa - Panama - no whois server assigned
    "pe" => "kero.yachay.pe", // Peru
    "pf" => "whois.registry.pf", // French Polynesia
    // pg - Papua New Guinea - no whois server assigned
    // ph - Philippines - no whois server assigned
    // pk - Pakistan - no whois server assigned
    "pl" => "whois.dns.pl", // Poland
    "pm" => "whois.nic.pm", // Saint Pierre and Miquelon (France)
    // pn - Pitcairn (New Zealand) - no whois server assigned
    "post" => "whois.dotpostregistry.net",
    "pr" => "whois.nic.pr", // Puerto Rico
    "pro" => "whois.dotproregistry.net",
    // ps - Palestine, State of - no whois server assigned
    "pt" => "whois.dns.pt", // Portugal
    "pw" => "whois.nic.pw", // Palau
    // py - Paraguay - no whois server assigned
    "qa" => "whois.registry.qa", // Qatar
    "re" => "whois.nic.re", // Reunion (France)
    "ro" => "whois.rotld.ro", // Romania
    "rs" => "whois.rnids.rs", // Serbia
    "ru" => "whois.tcinet.ru", // Russian Federation
    // rw - Rwanda - no whois server assigned
    "sa" => "whois.nic.net.sa", // Saudi Arabia
    "sb" => "whois.nic.net.sb", // Solomon Islands
    "sc" => "whois2.afilias-grs.net", // Seychelles
    // sd - Sudan - no whois server assigned
    "se" => "whois.iis.se", // Sweden
    "sg" => "whois.sgnic.sg", // Singapore
    "sh" => "whois.nic.sh", // Saint Helena
    "si" => "whois.arnes.si", // Slovenia
    "sk" => "whois.sk-nic.sk", // Slovakia
    // sl - Sierra Leone - no whois server assigned
    "sm" => "whois.nic.sm", // San Marino
    "sn" => "whois.nic.sn", // Senegal
    "so" => "whois.nic.so", // Somalia
    // sr - Suriname - no whois server assigned
    "st" => "whois.nic.st", // Sao Tome And Principe
    "su" => "whois.tcinet.ru", // Russian Federation
    // sv - El Salvador - no whois server assigned
    "sx" => "whois.sx", // Sint Maarten (dutch Part)
    "sy" => "whois.tld.sy", // Syrian Arab Republic
    // sz - Swaziland - no whois server assigned
    "tc" => "whois.meridiantld.net", // Turks And Caicos Islands
    // td - Chad - no whois server assigned
    "tel" => "whois.nic.tel",
    "tf" => "whois.nic.tf", // French Southern Territories
    // tg - Togo - no whois server assigned
    "th" => "whois.thnic.co.th", // Thailand
    "tj" => "whois.nic.tj", // Tajikistan
    "tk" => "whois.dot.tk", // Tokelau
    "tl" => "whois.nic.tl", // Timor-leste
    "tm" => "whois.nic.tm", // Turkmenistan
    "tn" => "whois.ati.tn", // Tunisia
    "to" => "whois.tonic.to", // Tonga
    "tp" => "whois.nic.tl", // Timor-leste
    "tr" => "whois.nic.tr", // Turkey
    "travel" => "whois.nic.travel",
    // tt - Trinidad And Tobago - no whois server assigned
    "tv" => "tvwhois.verisign-grs.com", // Tuvalu
    "tw" => "whois.twnic.net.tw", // Taiwan
    "tz" => "whois.tznic.or.tz", // Tanzania, United Republic Of
    "ua" => "whois.ua", // Ukraine
    "ug" => "whois.co.ug", // Uganda
    "uk" => "whois.nic.uk", // United Kingdom
    "us" => "whois.nic.us", // United States
    "uy" => "whois.nic.org.uy", // Uruguay
    "uz" => "whois.cctld.uz", // Uzbekistan
    // va - Holy See (vatican City State) - no whois server assigned
    "vc" => "whois2.afilias-grs.net", // Saint Vincent And The Grenadines
    "ve" => "whois.nic.ve", // Venezuela
    "vg" => "whois.adamsnames.tc", // Virgin Islands, British
    // vi - Virgin Islands, US - no whois server assigned
    // vn - Viet Nam - no whois server assigned
    // vu - Vanuatu - no whois server assigned
    "wf" => "whois.nic.wf", // Wallis and Futuna
    "ws" => "whois.website.ws", // Samoa
    "xxx" => "whois.nic.xxx",
    // ye - Yemen - no whois server assigned
    "yt" => "whois.nic.yt", // Mayotte
    "yu" => "whois.ripe.net");

function LookupDomain($domain){
    global $whoisservers;
    $domain_parts = explode(".", $domain);
    $tld = strtolower(array_pop($domain_parts));
    $whoisserver = $whoisservers[$tld];
    if(!$whoisserver) {
        return "Error: No appropriate Whois server found for $domain domain!";
    }
    $result = QueryWhoisServer($whoisserver, $domain);
    if(!$result) {
        return "Error: No results retrieved from $whoisserver server for $domain domain!";
    }
    else {
        while(strpos($result, "Whois Server:") !== FALSE){
            preg_match("/Whois Server: (.*)/", $result, $matches);
            $secondary = $matches[1];
            if($secondary) {
                $result = QueryWhoisServer($secondary, $domain);
                $whoisserver = $secondary;
            }
        }
    }
    return "$domain domain lookup results from $whoisserver server:\n\n" . $result;
}

function LookupIP($ip) {
    $whoisservers = array(
        //"whois.afrinic.net", // Africa - returns timeout error :-(
        "whois.lacnic.net", // Latin America and Caribbean - returns data for ALL locations worldwide :-)
        "whois.apnic.net", // Asia/Pacific only
        "whois.arin.net", // North America only
        "whois.ripe.net" // Europe, Middle East and Central Asia only
    );
    $results = array();
    foreach($whoisservers as $whoisserver) {
        $result = QueryWhoisServer($whoisserver, $ip);
        if($result && !in_array($result, $results)) {
            $results[$whoisserver]= $result;
        }
    }
    $res = "RESULTS FOUND: " . count($results);
    foreach($results as $whoisserver=>$result) {
        $res .= "\n\n-------------\nLookup results for " . $ip . " from " . $whoisserver . " server:\n\n" . $result;
    }
    return $res;
}

function ValidateIP($ip) {
    $ipnums = explode(".", $ip);
    if(count($ipnums) != 4) {
        return false;
    }
    foreach($ipnums as $ipnum) {
        if(!is_numeric($ipnum) || ($ipnum > 255)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return $ip;
}

function ValidateDomain($domain) {
    if(!preg_match("/^([-a-z0-9]{2,100})\.([a-z\.]{2,8})$/i", $domain)) {
        return false;
    }
    return $domain;
}

function QueryWhoisServer($whoisserver, $domain) {
    $port = 43;
    $timeout = 10;
    $fp = @fsockopen($whoisserver, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout) or die("Socket Error " . $errno . " - " . $errstr);
    //if($whoisserver == "whois.verisign-grs.com") $domain = "=".$domain; // whois.verisign-grs.com requires the equals sign ("=") or it returns any result containing the searched string.
    fputs($fp, $domain . "\r\n");
    $out = "";
    while(!feof($fp)){
        $out .= fgets($fp);
    }
    fclose($fp);

    $res = "";
    if((strpos(strtolower($out), "error") === FALSE) && (strpos(strtolower($out), "not allocated") === FALSE)) {
        $rows = explode("\n", $out);
        foreach($rows as $row) {
            $row = trim($row);
            if(($row != '') && ($row[0] != '#') && ($row[0] != '%')) {
                $res .= $row."\n";
            }
        }
    }
    return $res;
}
?>

<?php
if($domain) {
    $domain = trim($domain);
    if(substr(strtolower($domain), 0, 7) == "http://") $domain = substr($domain, 7);
    if(substr(strtolower($domain), 0, 4) == "www.") $domain = substr($domain, 4);
    if(ValidateIP($domain)) {
        $result = LookupIP($domain);
    }
    elseif(ValidateDomain($domain)) {
        $result = LookupDomain($domain);
    }
    else die("Invalid Input!");
    echo "<pre>";
    echo $result;
        echo "</pre>";

}
?>
```

I got this [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBO83.png)

I have tried some of the things but i didn't accomplish. So what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: I think that your problem is copy/pasting raw php codes into the laravel. You should care about laravel structure if you want to use ready codes in your project or you can search for laravel packages. I searched and found one: https://github.com/yassine-khachlek/laravel-whois-lookup

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I made some researches and i found this https://github.com/larvatecn/laravel-whois i guess this is more easy to setup.

Answer (score 0):

I found some package for laravel whois lookup. I am not gonna use raw php code, i guess that is the mistake i made. https://github.com/larvatecn/laravel-whois this is the package i am gonna use.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).